# Cumulate arrays from earlier rows (PySpark dataframe)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A (Python) example will make my question clear. Let's say I have a Spark dataframe of people who watched certain movies on certain dates, as follows:

```py
movierecord = spark.createDataFrame([("Alice", 1, ["Avatar"]),("Bob", 2, ["Fargo", "Tron"]),("Alice", 4, ["Babe"]), ("Alice", 6, ["Avatar", "Airplane"]), ("Alice", 7, ["Pulp Fiction"]), ("Bob", 9, ["Star Wars"])],["name","unixdate","movies"])
```

The schema and the dataframe defined by the above look as follows:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unixdate: long (nullable = true)
 |-- movies: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+-----+--------+------------------+
|name |unixdate|movies            |
+-----+--------+------------------+
|Alice|1       |[Avatar]          |
|Bob  |2       |[Fargo, Tron]     |
|Alice|4       |[Babe]            |
|Alice|6       |[Avatar, Airplane]|
|Alice|7       |[Pulp Fiction]    |
|Bob  |9       |[Star Wars]       |
+-----+--------+------------------+
```

I'd like to go from the above to generating a new dataframe column which holds **all *previous* movies seen by each user**, without duplicates ("previous" per the unixdate field). So it should look like this:

```
+-----+--------+------------------+------------------------+
|name |unixdate|movies            |previous_movies         |
+-----+--------+------------------+------------------------+
|Alice|1       |[Avatar]          |[]                      |
|Bob  |2       |[Fargo, Tron]     |[]                      |
|Alice|4       |[Babe]            |[Avatar]                |
|Alice|6       |[Avatar, Airplane]|[Avatar, Babe]          |
|Alice|7       |[Pulp Fiction]    |[Avatar, Babe, Airplane]|
|Bob  |9       |[Star Wars]       |[Fargo, Tron]           |
+-----+--------+------------------+------------------------+
```

How do I implement this in a nice efficient way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**SQL only** *without preserving the order* of objects:

- Required imports:

  ```py
  import pyspark.sql.functions as f
  from pyspark.sql.window import Window
  ```
- Window definition:

  ```py
  w = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("unixdate")
  ```
- Complete solution:

  ```py
  (movierecord
      # Flatten movies
      .withColumn("previous_movie", f.explode("movies"))
      # Collect unique
      .withColumn("previous_movies", f.collect_set("previous_movie").over(w))
      # Drop duplicates for a single unixdate
      .groupBy("name", "unixdate")
      .agg(f.max(f.struct(
          f.size("previous_movies"),
          f.col("movies").alias("movies"),
          f.col("previous_movies").alias("previous_movies")
      )).alias("tmp"))
      # Shift by one and extract
     .select(
         "name", "unixdate", "tmp.movies", 
         f.lag("tmp.previous_movies", 1).over(w).alias("previous_movies")))
  ```
- The result:

  ```
   +-----+--------+------------------+------------------------+
   |name |unixdate|movies            |previous_movies         |
   +-----+--------+------------------+------------------------+
   |Bob  |2       |[Fargo, Tron]     |null                    |
   |Bob  |9       |[Star Wars]       |[Fargo, Tron]           |
   |Alice|1       |[Avatar]          |null                    |
   |Alice|4       |[Babe]            |[Avatar]                |
   |Alice|6       |[Avatar, Airplane]|[Babe, Avatar]          |
   |Alice|7       |[Pulp Fiction]    |[Babe, Airplane, Avatar]|
   +-----+--------+------------------+------------------------+
  ```

**SQL an Python UDF** preserving the order:

- Imports:

  ```py
  import pyspark.sql.functions as f
  from pyspark.sql.window import Window
  from pyspark.sql import Column
  from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

  from typing import List, Union

  # https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz
  from toolz import unique, concat, compose
  ```
- UDF:

  ```py
  def flatten_distinct(col: Union[Column, str]) -> Column:
      def flatten_distinct_(xss: Union[List[List[str]], None]) -> List[str]:
          return compose(list, unique, concat)(xss or [])
      return f.udf(flatten_distinct_, ArrayType(StringType()))(col)
  ```
- Window definition as before.
- Complete solution:

  ```py
  (movierecord
      # Collect lists
      .withColumn("previous_movies", f.collect_list("movies").over(w))
      # Flatten and drop duplicates
      .withColumn("previous_movies", flatten_distinct("previous_movies"))
      # Shift by one
      .withColumn("previous_movies", f.lag("previous_movies", 1).over(w))
      # For presentation only
      .orderBy("unixdate"))
  ```
- The result:

  ```
  +-----+--------+------------------+------------------------+
  |name |unixdate|movies            |previous_movies         |
  +-----+--------+------------------+------------------------+
  |Alice|1       |[Avatar]          |null                    |
  |Bob  |2       |[Fargo, Tron]     |null                    |
  |Alice|4       |[Babe]            |[Avatar]                |
  |Alice|6       |[Avatar, Airplane]|[Avatar, Babe]          |
  |Alice|7       |[Pulp Fiction]    |[Avatar, Babe, Airplane]|
  |Bob  |9       |[Star Wars]       |[Fargo, Tron]           |
  +-----+--------+------------------+------------------------+
  ```

**Performance**:

I believe there is no efficient way to solve this given the constraints. Not only requested output requires a significant data duplication (data is binary encoded to fit Tungsten format, so you get possible compression but loose object identity) but also a number of operations which are expensive given Spark computing model including expensive grouping and sorting.

This should be fine if expect size of the `previous_movies` is bounded and small but won't be feasible in general.

Data duplication is pretty easy to address by keeping single, lazy history for an user. Not something that can be done in SQL but quite easy with low level RDD operations.

Explode and `collect_` pattern is expensive. If your requirements are strict but you want to improve performance you can use Scala UDF in place of Python one.